# Excel data not displaying

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that doesnt seem to be merging all the rows!
 I need it to merge even with empty columns.

For example:

On *Sheet CPW*, **Column W** is blank. So when merged all the entries for *CPW* should show blank in Column W and the information from *Sheet CCI* would only show.

That's just one example. There are many more on these two sheets.
This is my code for the merge. How can it be edited to do what I require?

```
Sub Combine()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables

    Dim r1, r2, r3, r4, ra, rb, rc, rd, re, rf, rg As Range
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Set r1 = Range("A:C")
    Set r2 = Range("E:X")
    Set r3 = Range("Y:AW")
    Set r4 = Range("AX:BK")

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Set ra = Range("A:A")
    Set rb = Range("C:C")
    Set rc = Range("B:B")
    Set rd = Range("D:G")
    Set re = Range("I:AL")
    Set rf = Range("AM:AP")
    Set rg = Range("AQ:BK")

    Set wrk = Workbooks.Add

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
    Sheets(2).Name = "CPW"
    r1.Copy Range("A1")
    r2.Copy Range("D1")
    r3.Copy Range("Y1")
    r4.Copy Range("AY1")
    Range("A1:BK100").Font.ColorIndex = 3

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
    Sheets(3).Name = "CCI"
    ra.Copy Range("A1")
    rb.Copy Range("B1")
    rc.Copy Range("C1")
    rd.Copy Range("D1")
    re.Copy Range("H1")
    rf.Copy Range("AM1")
    rg.Copy Range("AQ1")

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(1).Select
    Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
    Sheets(2).Activate
    Range("A2").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(J).Activate
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
        Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)

        Sheets(1).Select

        Range("A1:BK1000").Sort _
        Key1:=Range("E1"), Key2:=Range("J1"), Header:=xlYes
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Trim down your posted code to the minimum that produces the error. Also we'll need some more infor about the data and the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Select and Activate is not recommended (unless essential to the code’s objectives) because they are slow commands and are confusing.

You have blank columns because your copies do not line up.  With the creation of the source ranges so far from their use, this is not obvious.

My macro achieves the same result as yours.  I have bought all the code for copying together so it is much more obvious where you have left gaps.  I have included questions where I suspect your code does not do what you want.  I have included comments explaining aspects of your code I do not like.

Work through my code and study how I have achieved the same effects as yours.  Come back with questions as necessary but the more you can understand on your own, the faster you will develop your skills.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Combine()

  ' Here it does not really matter since J is only used in a small block of
  ' code but avoid names like J. When you return to update this macro in
  ' 12 months will you remember what J is? I have a system of names that I
  ' have used for years. I can look at a macro I wrote 5 years ago and
  ' immediately know what all the variables. This speeds the work of
  ' remembering what the macro did. If you do not like my naming system,
  ' design your own but have a system.

  ' "Integer" defines a 16-bit integer which requires special processing on
  ' a post-16-bit computer.  Use Long which defines a 32-bit integer
  'Dim J As Integer

  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim WbkThis As Workbook
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim Row1Next As Long
  Dim WbkNew As Workbook
  Dim WshtNew2 As Worksheet
  Dim WshtNew3 As Worksheet
  Dim WshtThis2 As Worksheet
  Dim WshtThis3 As Worksheet

  ' ThisWorkbook is the workbook containing the macro.  It is not
  ' necessarily the active workbook
  Set WbkThis = ThisWorkbook
  Set WshtThis2 = WbkThis.Worksheets("Sheet2")
  Set WshtThis3 = WbkThis.Worksheets("Sheet3")

  Set WbkNew = Workbooks.Add
  Set WshtNew2 = WbkNew.Worksheets(2)
  Set WshtNew3 = WbkNew.Worksheets(3)

  WshtNew2.Name = "CPW"
  WshtThis2.Range("A:C").Copy Destination:=WshtNew2.Range("A1")
  ' Note columns E:X are written to columns D:W.  X is left blank
  WshtThis2.Range("E:X").Copy Destination:=WshtNew2.Range("D1")
  WshtThis2.Range("Y:AW").Copy Destination:=WshtNew2.Range("Y1")
  ' Note the previous destination end in column AW while the next
  ' starts with AY.  Column AX is left blank.
  WshtThis2.Range("AX:BK").Copy Destination:=WshtNew2.Range("AY1")
  ' Why are only the first hundred rows coloured red?
  ' Why don't you colour column BL?
  WshtNew2.Range("A1:BK100").Font.ColorIndex = 3

  WshtNew3.Name = "CCI"
  WshtThis3.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=WshtNew3.Range("A1")
  ' Did you mean to reverse columns B and C?
  WshtThis3.Range("B:B").Copy Destination:=WshtNew3.Range("C1")
  WshtThis3.Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=WshtNew3.Range("B1")
  WshtThis3.Range("D:G").Copy Destination:=WshtNew3.Range("D1")
  WshtThis3.Range("I:AL").Copy Destination:=WshtNew3.Range("H1")
  WshtThis3.Range("AM:AP").Copy Destination:=WshtNew3.Range("AM1")
  WshtThis3.Range("AQ:BK").Copy Destination:=WshtNew3.Range("AQ1")

  'On Error Resume Next
  ' This statement means ignore all errors which you should never do.
  ' Use this statement so:
      'On Error Resume Next
      'Statement that may fail for reasons you cannot control or stop
      'On Error GoTo 0
      'If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ' No error
      'Else
        ' Display Err.Description or take corrective action according
        ' to value of Err.Number
      'End If


    'Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    ' Since you have just created the worksheet it is probably safe to
    ' use "CurrentRegion".  However, Excel's definition of CurrentRegion
    ' is not always what you might expect.

    With WbkNew
      With .Worksheets(1)
        .Name = "Combined"
        ' Did you mean to copy row 2?
        WshtNew2.Rows(2).Copy Destination:=.Rows(1)
      End With
      Row1Next = 3        ' Next free row in worksheets(1)
      For InxWsht = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        ' This Find searches backwards from A1 by row for the first cell
        ' containing a value. This will give you what you expect more
        ' often that CurrentRegion
        With Worksheets(InxWsht)
          Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
          If Rng Is Nothing Then
            ' Probably not necessary here but best to be safe.  If a worksheet
            ' is empty Find will return Nothing
          Else
            .Rows("2:" & Rng.Row).Copy Destination:=WbkNew.Worksheets(1).Cells(Row1Next, 1)
            ' Unless I absolutely know that column A will be the last column with
            ' a value, I prefer to caluclate the next free row.
            Row1Next = Row1Next + Rng.Row - 1
          End If
        End With
      Next
      ' I do not see the point of having the Sort within the or Loop
      With .Worksheets(1)
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Range("E1"), Key2:=Range("J1"), Header:=xlYes
      End With
    End With

End Sub
```